# Optimizing Python 3n + 1 Programming Challenge

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to find a efficient solution for the 3n + 1 problem on [uvaonlinejudge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36). The code I have uses memoization using a dictionary. Can anyone suggest an improvement(s) that will help with the execution time of this code? At the moment I am getting a 'Time limit Exceeded' error when I submit the code. If anyone has a working solution to the problem please share it with me. PLEASE DON'T mark this post as DUPLICATE. I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401993/uva-online-judge-python-time-limit-exceeded) post and others on stackoverflow but they don't answer the question posted here. My code is as below:

```
import sys

def recCycleLength(n,cycLenDict):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n not in cycLenDict:
        if n%2==0:
            cycLen = recCycleLength(n//2, cycLenDict)
            cycLenDict[n] = cycLen + 1
            return cycLen+1
        else:
            cycLen = recCycleLength(3*n+1, cycLenDict)
            cycLenDict[n] = cycLen + 1
            return cycLen+1
    else:
        return cycLenDict[n]


def maxCycle(a, b):
    i = a
    mydict = {} 
    maxLength = 1
    while i <= b:
        m = recCycleLength(i, mydict)
        if m > maxLength:
            maxLength = m
        i = i + 1
    return maxLength


for line in sys.stdin:
    curr_line=line.split()
    num1 = int(curr_line[0])
    num2 = int(curr_line[1])
    if num1>num2:
        num1, num2 = num2, num1
    m = maxCycle(num1, num2)
    print("{} {} {}".format(num1, num2, m))
```

Comment: If you have working solution please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: that can be discussed: the OP doesn't want to improve readability but speed.

Comment: if you submit it, please provide the input in the question. I tried with sample inputs in the page and it was very fast. So I missed something.

Comment: uvaonlinejudge does not provide users with the test cases that it runs submitted code on. Sample inputs are just so that users can test their code for errors before submitting.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/143832/9357).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in your code. Actually, you are not saving `cycLenDict` generated on the previous interval for next one. And this is why your code is so "slow" because it will generate all possible endings over and over again. Just move it in global scope or make something like this:

```
import sys


def rec(n, cache):
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    if n % 2 == 0:
        cycle = rec(n//2, cache)
    else:
        cycle = rec(3*n+1, cache)
    cache[n] = cycle + 1
    return cache[n]


def cycle(a, b, cache):
    return max(rec(i, cache) for i in range(a, b+1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache = {1: 1}
    for line in sys.stdin:
        a, b = map(int, line.split())
        a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)
        m = cycle(a, b, cache)
        print("{} {} {}".format(a, b, m))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to do the right thing to execute `maxCycle` optimally by caching all calculated results in `mydict`.

However, the input to the application consists of many pairs of values to be processed and `maxCycle` will reset `mydict = {}` and calculate everything from scratch.

I suggest remembering the results globally instead. A simple modification of the original code would be:

```
cycLenDict = {}   # global dictionary

def recCycleLength(n):   # no cycLenDict argument
    if n==1:
        return 1
    if n not in cycLenDict:
        # ...

def maxCycle(a, b):
    # ...

    while i <= b:
        m = recCycleLength(i)   # no myDict argument
```

To make everything a little bit nicer looking (without any difference performance-wise, compared to the solution above), make a decorator which remembers the results, so that the remainder of the code does not have to take care of that:

```
def memoize(func):
    """decorate any function which takes positional arguments to cache its results"""

    func.results = {}  # results are stored globally as the funtion's attribute

    def memoized(*a):        # memoized version of func
        if a not in func.results:       # if not cached
            func.results[a] = func(*a)  # save to cache
        return func.results[a]          # return from cache
    return memoized


@memoize       # with this, recCycleLength is called only once for every n value
def recCycleLength(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    elif n%2==0:
        return recCycleLength(n//2) + 1
    else:
        return recCycleLength(3*n+1) + 1


def maxCycle(a, b):
    return max(recCycleLength(i) for i in range(a, b+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
def cycle(current, count=1):
if current == 1:
    return count
if current % 2 == 0:
    return cycle(current / 2, count + 1)
return cycle(current * 3 + 1, count + 1)

def max_cycles(lower, upper):
    max = 0
    for current in range(lower, upper):
        result = cycle(current, 1)
        if result > max:
            max = result
    return max


def main(i, j):
    if i > j:
        (i, j) = (j, i)
    print (i, j, max_cycles(i, j))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:   
        print 'usage: python filename argv1 argv2'
        print 'exiting'
        exit(0)
    main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```